# Regex, not replacing when there is 2 characters the same?

Tags: php, regex

I need to be able to replace `*hello*` with `somethinghellosomething`. I can do this with the regex `#\*(.*?)\*#`. The issue is, I want to ignore any with `**hello**`. I have tried `#\*([^\s].*?)\*#`, where it sort of works, but returns `*somethinghellosomething*`, instead of just `**hello**`. What do I need to add to my expression, to ensure it doesn't replace any `**` encased strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match only when not preceded or followed by another `*`.

```
(?<!\*)\*([^*]+)\*(?!\*)
```

Also, note that I changed your `.*?` to `[^*]+`. Otherwise, it could match two consecutive asterisks because `.*?` could match on *nothing*.

Example: http://regexr.com?33sp0

---

Piece by piece, this is:

```
(?<!\*)    # not preceded by an asterisk
\*         # an asterisk
([^*]+)    # at least one non-asterisk character
\*         # an asterisk
(?!\*)     # not followed by an asterisk
```

Comment: Thanks for the piece-by-piece breakdown, it helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 #(\*+)(.*?)(\*+)#
```

sample code

```
 $notecomments=" **hello**  *hello*   ***hello*** ****hello**** ";
 $output=preg_replace_callback(array("#(\*+)(.*?)(\*+)#"),function($matches){
if($matches[1]=="*")
  return 'something'.$matches[2].'something';
else
  return $matches[0];

},' '.$notecomments.' ');
```

output:

```
  **hello** somethinghellosomething ***hello*** ****hello****
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '**something**   **another**  *hello*';
function myfunc($matches)
{
 if($matches[0][0] == '*' && $matches[0][1] == '*'){
  return $matches[0];
 }else{
  return str_replace('*', 'something', $matches[0]);
 }
}
echo preg_replace_callback("/(\*){1,2}([^*]+)(\*){1,2}/","myfunc", $text);
```